# MySQL Foreign Key Error Code 1215

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm receiving an error attempting to add columns to a table with a foreign key to an existing table.  Here are the two SQL statements that fail:

```
ALTER TABLE current_teams ADD COLUMN master_team_id INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_master_team_id(master_team_id) REFERENCES master_teams(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE current_teams ADD COLUMN player_id INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_player_id(player_id) REFERENCES players(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The error I'm getting is: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

When running innodb, the more detailed message says:

> 2016-02-03 17:22:43 0x3210 Error in foreign key constraint of table
>   lod/#sql-1d58_6:FOREIGN KEY fk_master_team_id(master_team_id)
>   REFERENCES master_teams(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE: Cannot resolve table
>   name close to: (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

The weird thing is that on other tables, adding the exact same foreign key works fine.  These statements run without issue:

```
ALTER TABLE team_scouting ADD COLUMN master_team_id INT, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_master_team_id(master_team_id) REFERENCES master_teams(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE team_scouting ADD COLUMN player_id INT, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_player_id(player_id) REFERENCES players(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE masterteams` is as follows:

```
'CREATE TABLE `master_teams` (
  `team_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_salary` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `penalty` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `username` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rights` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Only on this 'current_teams' table does adding the column/foreign key fail.  Any help would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE master_teams` and add the results to your question.

Comment: Does master_teams table exist when you try to run this alter table?

Comment: You can't use the same constraint name `fk_master_team_id` repeatedly. Each constraint needs to have a unique name.

Comment: @Barmar I thought of that too and tried renaming it, but still didn't work.  Also, other tables for which I have the same named foreign key, still work.  Only this one table fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `master_teams` table is not an InnoDB table, so the InnoDB engine "can't resolve" the table name. Try updating it like so:

```
ALTER TABLE master_teams ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As Barmar says in the comments, [constraint names do need to be globally unique](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). If you don't specify the name MySQL will make one up for you:

> If the `CONSTRAINT`***`symbol`*** clause is given, the ***symbol*** value, if used, must be unique in the database. A duplicate ***symbol*** will result in an error similar to: `ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.#sql-211d_3' (errno: 121).` If the clause is not given, or a ***symbol*** is not included following the `CONSTRAINT` keyword, a name for the constraint is created automatically.

Comment: Thanks - the ENGINE was the issue and I'm no longer getting the error.  However the constraint name didn't throw an error even though they weren't unique.

Comment: I wouldn't tempt fate, and stick with unique names.